# Calculating Median using Percentile on Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, percentile

I have a large table with over 18M rows and I want to calculate Median and I am using PRECENTILE for that. However the time taken is around 17 minutes, which is not ideal.

Here is my query

```
WITH raw_data AS
(
  SELECT name AS series,
         (duration) /(60000) AS value
  FROM warehouse.table
),
quartiles AS
(
  SELECT series,
         value,
         PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS q1,
         MEDIAN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS median,
         PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS q3
  FROM raw_data
)
SELECT series,
       MIN(value) AS minimum,
       AVG(q1) AS q1,
       AVG(median) AS median,
       AVG(q3) AS q3,
       MAX(value) AS maximum
FROM quartiles
GROUP BY 1
```

Is there a way I could speed this up?

Thanks

Comment: I am surprised with your timings/data volume! Is anything else running? how many nodes of what type do you have? I just ran your code against my data which was 26M rows and it took 45 seconds. Medians and percentiles are quite hard computations in a large database so < 45 seconds is the time i would expect it to take.

Comment: I am using 8 nodes of compute.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is asking Redshift to do a lot of work. The data must be distributed according to your `PARTITION` column and the sorted according to your `ORDER BY` column.

There are two options to make it faster:

1. **Use more hardware**. Redshift performance scales very linearly. Most queries will run 2x as fast on 2x as much hardware.
2. **Do some work in advance**. You can maximize performance for this query by restructuring the table. Use the `PARTITION` column as the distribution key (`DISTKEY(series)`) and first sort key. Use the `ORDER BY` column as the second sort key (`SORTKEY(series,value)`). This will minimize the work required to answer the query. Time savings will vary but I see a 3m30s `PERCENTILE_CONT` query drop to 30s using this approach on my small test cluster.

Answer (score 0):

To get some speed up of part of this, try the following

```
SELECT distinct 
       series,
             value,
             PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS q1,
             MEDIAN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS median,
             PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY value) OVER (PARTITION BY series) AS q3

  FROM warehouse.table
```

This may be faster as it is more likely to correctly use the sort/dist of your table.
You would have to calculate the min and max elsewhere. but at least see if it runs faster.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for your suggestion. However I see improvement of over 2 minutes after using your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can try `APPROXIMATE  PERCENTILE_DISC ( percentile )` function which is optimized for working on distributed data with low error percentage, incl. median that will be 0.5